# GPU and `jax` performance mysteries

Tags: python, numpy, performance, jax

I have been playing with `jax` lately, and it is very impressive, but then the following set of experiments confused me greatly:

First, we set up the timer utility:

```
import time
def timefunc(foo, *args):
   tic = time.perf_counter()
   tmp = foo(*args)
   toc = time.perf_counter()
   print(toc - tic)
   return tmp
```

Now, let’s see what happens when we compute the eigenvalues of a random symmetric matrix matrix, thus (`jnp` is `jax.numpy`, so the `eigh` is done on the GPU)

```
def jfunc(n):
  tmp = np.random.randn(n, n)
  return jnp.linalg.eigh(tmp + tmp.T)

def nfunc(n):
  tmp = np.random.randn(n, n)
  return np.linalg.eigh(tmp + tmp.T)
```

Now for the timings (the machine is an nVidia DGX box, so the GPU is an A100, while the CPUs are some AMD EPYC2 parts.

```
>>> e1 = timefunc(nfunc, 10)
0.0002442029945086688
>>> e2 = timefunc(jfunc, 10)
0.013523647998226807
>>> e1 = timefunc(nfunc, 100)
0.11742364699603058
>>> e2 = timefunc(jfunc, 100)
0.11005625998950563
>>> e1 = timefunc(nfunc, 1000)
0.6572738009999739
>>> e2 = timefunc(jfunc, 1000)
0.5530761769914534
>>> e1 = timefunc(nfunc, 10000)
36.22587636699609
>>> e2 = timefunc(jfunc, 10000)
8.867857075005304
```

You will notice that the crossover is somewhere around 1000.  Initially, I thought this was because of the overhead of moving stuff to/from the GPU, but if you define yet another function:

```
def jjfunc(n):
  key=jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
  tmp = jax.random.normal(key, [n, n])
  return jnp.linalg.eigh(tmp + tmp.T)


>>> e1=timefunc(jjfunc, 10)
0.01886096798989456
>>> e1=timefunc(jjfunc, 100)
0.2756766739912564
>>> e1=timefunc(jjfunc, 1000)
0.7205733209993923
>>> e1=timefunc(jjfunc, 10000)
6.8624101399909705
```

Note that the small examples are actually (much) slower than moving the `numpy` array to the GPU and back.

So, my question is: what is going on, and is there a silver bullet? Is this a `jax` implementation bug?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your timings are reflective of actual JAX vs. numpy performance, for a few reasons:

- JAX's computation model uses [Asynchronous Dispatch](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async_dispatch.html), which means that JAX operations return before the computation is finished. As mentioned at that link, you can use the `block_until_ready()` method to ensure you are timing the computation rather than the dispatch.
- Because operations like `eigh` are [JIT-compiled by default](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/5ae079567467c1ce0432ad19ef297b3d6050f2af/jax/_src/numpy/linalg.py#L319-L320), the first time you run them for a given size will incur the one-time compilation cost. Subsequent runs will be faster as JAX caches previous compilations.
- Your computations are indeed being foiled by device transfer costs. It's easiest to see if you measure it directly:

  ```python
  def transfer(n):
    tmp = np.random.randn(n, n)
    return jnp.array(tmp).block_until_ready()
  timefunc(transfer, 10000);
  # 4.600406924000026
  ```
- Your `jjfunc` combines the `eigh` call with the `jax.random.normal` call. The latter is slower than numpy's random number generation, and I believe is dominating the difference for small `n`.
- Unrelated to JAX, but in general using `time.time` for profiling Python code can give you misleading results. Modules like `timeit` are much better for this kind of thing, particularly when you're dealing with microbenchmarks that complete in fractions of a second.

If you're interested in accurate benchmarks of JAX vs. Numpy versions of algorithms, I'd suggest isolating exactly the operations you're interested in benchmarking (i.e. generate the data & do any device transfer outside the benchmarks). Read up on the advice in [Asynchronous Dispatch](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/async_dispatch.html) in JAX as it relates to benchmarking, and check out [Python's `timeit` Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) for tips on getting accurate timings of small code snippets (though I find the [`%timeit` magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit) more convenient if working IPython or Jupyter notebook).

Comment: I am a little confused by the JIT remark. Do "built-ins" like `linalg.eigh` benefit from JIT-ing? Even if they do, `jfunc` and `jjfunc` were run in the same session, so, as you say, at least one of them (`jjfunc`) should have benefitted from JIT-ing. No?

Comment: `linalg.eigh` is JIT-compiled by default ([source](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/5ae079567467c1ce0432ad19ef297b3d6050f2af/jax/_src/numpy/linalg.py#L319-L320)): it does benefit from this JITting in that it executes faster on subsequent runs, but it would not benefit from and additional JIT wrapper from the user, because it's already compiled. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, but that would mean that all the `jjfunc` runs have benefitted from JIT. Now, about your `timeit` comment: surely for code that takes as long as this, it is not really material which timer we use, no?

Comment: Yes, my point was to be careful about the effect of JIT, or else differences in timings due to compilation/no compilation might be misattributed to other reasons. Regarding `timeit`: it does a number of things to ensure that other sources of noise don't affect your benchmarks, so it's good practice to use that no matter how long your runs will take.